# Must Java implementation support identifiers starting with Unicode letters which aren't ASCII?

Tags: java, unicode

From The Java Language Specification Java SE 8 Edition (section 3.8) it seems that Java letters must include ASCII letters

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.

but may not include other Unicode letters (since the following sentence contains **may** not **must**):

> Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set,
>   which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today,
>   including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This
>   allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are
>   written in their native languages.

Is that correct that the implementation conforms to the specification even if it doesn't support non-ASCII letters in the identifiers?

If that is the case then the sentence "*This allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are written in their native languages.*" doesn't make much sense - since it advises using features which may not be supported by all implementations.

Comment: It seems that the JLS doesn't list all Java Letters. They are defined as any character for which `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns true. Presumably this leeway is given to allow flexible evolution of the Unicode standard without requiring wording changes in the JLS. The details are then [in that function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart(char)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the usage of the word "may" here. The sentence is to be read as "It is *allowed* to draw letters and digits from the entire Unicode character set,..."

Thus, the implementation has to support the whole Unicode set.